# Intel realsense D435 Pointcloud2 without RGB

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I was wondering if there is a way to have access to the *XYZ PointCloud2* instead of the *XYZRGB PointCloud2* in the [realsense2_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/realsense2_camera) ROS Package.

The idea is to use as less as possible the CPU computational power.

I have looked at [this solution](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/issues/347) but it was not working properly.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308978/intel-realsense-d435-pointcloud2-without-rgb/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2018-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the solution in the last version of the  [realsense2_camera](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense).

The following configuration should be defined in order to achieve the PointCloud withou RGB:

```
<!-- Intel Realsense D435 driver -->
<include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/rs_camera.launch">
<arg name="pointcloud_texture_stream" default="RS2_STREAM_ANY"/>  
<arg name="enable_pointcloud"         default="true"/>
<arg name="enable_color"        default="false"/>
<arg name="enable_depth"        default="true"/>
<arg name="enable_infra2"        default="false"/>
<arg name="enable_infra1"        default="false"/>
<arg name="align_depth"         default="false"/>
<arg name="depth_width"         default="640"/>
<arg name="depth_height"        default="480"/>
</include>
```

Unfortunately the current version does not support the *RS2_STREAM_DEPTH* therefore the result is not the same as I wished cause when you choose the *RS2_STREAM_ANY* the PointCloud will have more than twice of Points which leads to have even a higher CPU consumption with respect to the PointCloud with RGB.

---

Originally posted by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) with karma: 264 on 2018-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1